# MYSQL cleaning text string keeping alpha characters and white space

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to write a function that cleans a text string in MySQL. It works fine but I can't get REGEXP to leave white space in. The current statement is

```
IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' THEN
```

obviously this is going to take out anything thats not an alpha character but how do I add white space into the list?

I've adapted the code from another post. The full function is

```
    CREATE FUNCTION alphanum( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END;
```

Comment: have you tried `[:blank:]` ?

Comment: How would I add that in? I've tried IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z]|[:blank:]' THEN and also IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z:blank:' THEN  but neither work?

Comment: Have you tried `[A-Za-z ]` (there is a white space at the end)

Comment: yes that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.. I was declaring variables as type CHAR. This wasn't allowing the white space to be stored.

Amended the function accordingly and it now works.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION alphanum( str VARCHAR(100) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z ]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z]+' THEN
```

or

```
IF c  REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+[[:blank:]]+[A-Za-z]+' THEN
```

This matches words like

```
A B
A BB
AA B
AA BB
...
```

use `+` for 1 or more /
use `*` for 0 or more